# How do I get the values from one branch to search into another branch and populate a Firebase Recycler View Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project for an app in Android which involves groups, users and chats within these groups. Now, I'm having trouble to make the users only see their own groups and keep those updated for everyone else if something in them changes.

My Firebase structure is something similar to this:

Groups
    |
    |
    |---- Group 1
    |       |
    |               |---- Data of the group
    |               |---- ...
    |---- Group 2
                    |
                    |---- Data of the group
                    |---- ...

Users
            |
            |
            |---- User 1
            |
            |---- Data of the user
            |---- ...

User_Groups
    |
    |
    |---- |---- User 1
                    |
                    |---- Admin
                                      
                                      |---- Group 1 (which this user is the admin.)
                                      |
                                   |---- Group 2 (which this user is the admin.)

So with that, I'd like to get the Group 1 key which is inside the User_Groups --> User 1 --> Admin. And then take the key to search in the Groups branch for the specified group. And I need to do that for every group of the user.
And when I get all the groups, show them in a list.

Basically I am having big trouble showing the groups that the user is the admin. of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the group keys, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference adminRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User_Groups").child("User1").child("Admin");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String groupKey = (String) ds.getKey();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
adminRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, but maybe my explanation was not clear enough. I'm having trouble afterwards, when I try to get the groups (in the branch Groups) of which I already have the keys. Thanks!

Comment: Which groups? Show me on your database tree or give the exact reference. Or give a simple example.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/75ef55739624cbac16508887e1aba800 Getting the key of the red circle (which I can do with your code) I'd like to get the key of the blue circle. And if the user had more groups, get those groups too.

Comment: Why do you need that key? As i see in your screenshot, you already have it. That key from the red circle is actually the unique id generated by the `push()` method when you create `Grups` childrens. So when you generate that key, store it in a variable and than use it again in your reference. To store that random generated key use this code: `String groupKey = yourRef.getKey()` after you use the `push()` method.

Comment: But how can I filter those keys in the Grups branch? Because now there is one user, but there will be more and they can not have access to all the groups, just the ones that they created.

Comment: You cannot filter those unique id's. What can you filter, is the data inside those id's. But from what can i see, you have all the data you need to get into each node of your database.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies all of my doubts, thank you very much! You're a legend. :D

Comment: Ah, thank you. If you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting it.